# Add Time Machine files to an existing account with Migration Assistant

Tags: backup, time-machine, user-account, migration, migration-assistant

I have a Time Machine backup from Mac A (now retired), containing 4 accounts worth of data. I would like to *add* the data from one of these accounts to an existing account on Mac B (replacement for Mac A).

I thought this would be possible with Migration Assistant, but when I run it on Mac B, tell it to restore from the Time Machine backup and select just the account I want to migrate, it seems to want to *replace all accounts* on Mac B - it complains there won't be an Administrator account on the Mac after the migration. One of the existing accounts on Mac B *is* an Administrator.

My question is therefore:

Does anyone know how to wholesale add user data from a Time Machine backup from one Mac to an existing account on another Mac? Things like the Keychain need to be restored from Time Machine backup.

Failing which, is it possible to *just replace a single account* from a Time Machine backup, and how would I go about doing this?